# Setting up a virtual environment with virtualenv gives "SyntaxError: invalid syntax python3"

Tags: python, syntax-error, virtualenv

When trying to set up a virtual environment for TensorFlow in Python 3.6.7 with:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./venv
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax python3
```

Comment: ```virtualenv --version``` what's your version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this `python3 -m venv env`